# Why I get error "Invalid merchant account"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, rubygems, report

I want to get PayPal reports and for this reason I installed paypal-report gem.

Can someone look are my credentials are correct or for Reporting API usage I need some special account ?

I have verified bussiness account.

Here is my code:

```
  require 'paypal/report'
  api = Paypal::Report.new("my secure account MerchantID", "mypassword", "my secure account MerchantID", "PayPalUK")
  puts api.daily.inspect
```

I also tried to enter my email instead of MerchanID, but it didn't work.

and this gives me error:

```
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/paypal-report-0.1.2/lib/paypal/report.rb:141
  :in `block in request': Invalid merchant account (RuntimeError)
```

I tried to inspect api value, by using puts api and here is result:

```
        puts api
         //and result: 
        #<Paypal::Report:0x27a4310>
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing 'PayPalUK' in there, I've got a suspicion the gem you're using is for PayPal Payflow services (and when it comes to reporting, that would be XML Reporting).
Seeing as you mention having a regular 'verified business account', I don't think you'd have access to Payflow API calls. Thus, no correct credentials to enter there.

What PayPal API call are you trying to use? Is it TransactionSearch you're looking for?
If so, try the [ruby-paypal](http://ruby-paypal.rubyforge.org/) gem.
(Note, I haven't tested it, but it's the first one a quick Google search for "PayPal TransactionSearch gem"  returned.)

Comment: Thanks. I just can't decide how to solve my task:in project I need to show to users financial reports - I can create them by myself and don't tell it to my employer, that it didn't connect do PayPal or tell him, that Reporting only for Pro account.
 There is function transaction_search, but is seems to be only for Subscriptions. 
What you can say about that ?